# Sort based on comma separated words

Tags: regular-expression, sort

Normal command :sort can sort lines based on column or virtual column (`\%c` or `\%v`), could the higher level logical column be used as sorting key? Using regular expression looks a little complex for this scenario (the column is around the end of the line?) and it looks similar as what the sort utility does (`sork -k`), but sort with this functionality is unavailable on Windows. Vim plug-in will also help.

For example, I'd like to sort the 2 lines below according to the last column separated by comma. My real scenario has much more columns and string pattern. Specify column delimiter will simplify it a lot.

```
xxx,yyy,zzz,0x123
zzxz,xxxx,yyyy,0x121
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vim's sort allows you to either skip `{pattern}`, or only consider it (with the `r` flag). A regular expression for the last comma-delimited column is easy to formulate: Skip everything until and including the last comma in a line:

```
:sort/.*,/
```

For any other column, I would use the `r` flag, and skip N (here: `2`) previous columns via `\zs`:

```
:sort/\([^,]*,\)\{2}\zs[^,]*/
```

Comment: Since the last column happens to be a hex number using the `x` flag might also be helpful.

Comment: This looks great. The last column may be a special case. Any simple representation for the middle columns?

Comment: I thought you were able to come up with something for that, but here you are. Please accept my (edited) answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it. Thanks!